# Read multiple files using filereader in react js

Tags: reactjs, filereader

I tried to upload Multiple files and wants to read the content of the file for encrypt the data.
I can able to read the single file properly , but I can't do it while upload multiple files am getting error reader is busy.
If I create new Filereader while onloadend it gives me null value of content.

### React JS - sample code:

```
let reader = new FileReader();
class FilReaderComp extends Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {

}}
upLoadFileFolderFunc(e){
e.preventDefault();
let fileitemsList = e.target.files;
for (let i = 0; i < fileitemsList.length; i++) {
  let fileitems = fileitemsList[i];
  reader.onloadend = this.handleFileRead;
  reader.readAsText(fileitems);
  }
}

handleFileRead = (e) => {
const content = reader.result; here am reading content of the file

//here doing my function after getting content
}
render(){
return(
<input  type="file" className="custom-file-input" style={{display:"hide"}}
            onChange={this.upLoadFileFolderFunc} multiple/>
);}

export default withRouter(FilReaderComp);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try wrapping your onload function in another function and enclose the filereader in the loop. Here the closure gives you access to each file being processed in turn via the variable `f`:

```
function openFiles(evt){
    var files = evt.target.files;

    for (var i = 0, len = files.length; i < len; i++) {
        var file = files[i];

        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = (function(f) {
            return function(e) {
                // Here you can use `e.target.result` or `this.result`
                // and `f.name`.
            };
        })(file);

        reader.readAsText(file);
    }
}
```